# Setting headers before requesting JS / CSS Files

Tags: xmlhttprequest, requirejs

I am using `xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Basic ' + token);`

to set my custom headers for loading files via text.js

```
 config: {
        text: {
            onXhr: function (xhr, url) {
               xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization','Basic ' + token);
            }
        }
    }
```

While all the HTML resources loaded is being requested via this custom header. But when I checked in Chrome, none of the JS or CSS files requests are carrying these headers.

How should I ensure the JS / CSS etc files are also requested with these headers?

Answer (score 0):

Possible cause could be that, these requests are fired by the browser while interpreting the HTML page. As these requests are fired by the browser and not the application, this snippet will not be able to catch that. You can try using the [Web Request API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webRequest) for doing this.

If the header that you are trying to add is common across all the requests, you can try using cookies to get that info to the server. I'm not so sure about your use case, the cookie solution might vary as per the sensitivity of the data. This [link](https://scotch.io/@PratyushB/local-storage-vs-session-storage-vs-cookie) will give a quick overview of various stores.